# C++ Error: undefine reference to main in class

Tags: c++

I'm using code block in linux. When I try to build my cpp file where class Position is define, it gives an error-

> in function '_start':
>   undefined reference to 'main'

Even after object file has been created.

[All this files are in the same folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9P59v.jpg)

**This is the cpp file where Position is define**

```
#include "POSITION.h"

std::string Position::pos(int num) {
    switch(num) {
        case 0: return "\0";
        break;
        case 1: return "st";
        break;
        case 2: return "nd";
        break;
        case 3: return "rd";
        break;
        default: return "th";
        break;
    }
}
```

**This is the header file**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

class Position
{
public:
    std::string pos(int num);
};
```

Comment: You need to have a `main` function in one of the cpp files you're linking with. Unless you're building a library.

Answer (score 2):

Every C or C++ program starts at the [`main`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function) function, e.g.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // do something
    return 0;
}
```

Since your program has only a `Position` class and no `main`, the linker complains about that fact.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that all C++ programs need an entry point. The compiler is looking for `int main()`, but it does not exist, so the program can't be <s>compiled</s> linked. If you want you could just add something like `int main() { return 0; }` to the end of your program if all you're trying to do is make sure it builds properly.

Comment: "so the program can't be compiled" - It can be *compiled* just fine, it just cannot be *linked*.

Comment: Right. I'm still somewhat new at C++ myself.